# What do people mean when they just type こん？

Tags: usage

I see it chat rooms all the time and I have no clue what it means.

Answer (score 7):

Should mean こんにちは (Good day) or depending on the time こんばんわ (Good evening).
Same as おは for おはよう :)

Comment: Ohh wow I haven't even thought about it like that, I caught on that　おは was a shorter version for おはようございます but I probably never would've guessed こん was the same thing, thanks!